Debugging RCPP with VS Code
I am trying to reproduce the example here to debug RCPP code with VS Code on Windows.
Here is my launch.json config:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug R Package",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.1/bin/x64/R",
      "args": [
        "--vanilla",
        "-e",
        "devtools::test()"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "debug",
    }
  ]
}

Here is the c_cpp_properties.json config:
{
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/**",
          "C:/rtools40/mingw64/include",
          "C:/rtools40/mingw64/include/c++/8.3.0",
          "C:/rtools40/mingw64/include/c++/8.3.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
          "C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.1/include",
          "C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.1/library/Rcpp/include",
          "C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-4.2.1/library/RcppArmadillo/include"
        ],
        "defines": [
          "_DEBUG",
          "UNICODE",
          "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }

But when I try to debug, the code executes but does not stop at breakpoints.
I have tried to put calc_sum(c(1, 2, 3)) in tools\test.R and change the launch config with:
"args": [
    "--vanilla",
    "-e",
    "devtools::load_all();source('tools/test.R)'"
],

but that does not work either, the debugger does not stop at breakpoints.
Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

I'm not sure that this is supported on Windows. See the GitHub issue, running example on Windows.

Alright, I will try to make it work on Linux then, thanks!

in my experience Rcpp is kind of a pain on Windows (especially in corporate environments where directories such as OneDrive are forced to have spaces in them) but works beautifully on WSL2.

Yep I've just managed to make it work on WSL2, was very straightforward. Thanks again  for your help!

@SamR  You point the finger at Rcpp when you should point the finger at R and its use of gcc via MinGW.   Great tools. but pretty alien to everything customized to Visual Studio / Visual Code under Windows.  WSL2 is indeed a great helper there.

@AdaLovelace I'm sure you're right. It is odd that the R for Windows FAQ says We tried to make R to work with space in file names, but building of some packages from source may not work as this is little tested but then the default R installation path on Windows is in the Program Files folder. In any case I have given up on doing anything in R or any other language outside of WSL - there's just so much less friction.

R works great on Windows if you are careful and play by its rules.  Which means work like a Unix person (as WSL2 also allows now, explicitly).   Mising with Visual C++ and all its tools simple never worked, and never will (real well).  Different toolchain and stack.  Many people moved away from R-work-on-Windows, many still continue because of constraints.
